# iTunesConnect AngularJS Error

Tags: ios, angularjs, app-store-connect

Sorry if this is out of topic.

I was about to submit my app for review, when suddenly upon login I was shown nothing but a blank white page. Usually I can find the "Manage my apps", "Users", etc.

Upon closer inspection on the browser console, it seems that iTunesConnect is using AngularJS 1.12.10 and something inside is causing this error:
[https://docs.angularjs.org/error/$injector/modulerr](https://docs.angularjs.org/error/$injector/modulerr?p0=itcApp&p1=Error:%20%5B$injector:modulerr%5D%20http:%2F%2Ferrors.angularjs.org%2F1.2.16%2F$injector%2Fmodulerr%3Fp0%3Dui.router%26p1%3DError%253A%2520%255B%2524injector%253Anomod%255D%2520http%253A%252F%252Ferrors.angularjs.org%252F1.2.16%252F%2524injector%252Fnomod%253Fp0%253Dui.router%250A%2520%2520%2520%2520at%2520Error%2520(native)%250A%2520%2520%2520%2520at%2520https%253A%252F%252Fitunesconnect.apple.com%252Fc%252F6438ebc13eb4937a89f42b80f9064d41%252Fitc%252Fjs%252Fcompiled%252Flib%252Fvendor.js%253A25%253A449%250A%2520%2520%2520%2520at%2520https%253A%252F%252Fitunesconnect.apple.com%252Fc%252F6438ebc13eb4937a89f42b80f9064d41%252Fitc%252Fjs%252Fcompiled%252Flib%252Fvendor.js%253A25%253A7289%250A%2520%2520%2520%2520at%2520https%253A%252F%252Fitunesconnect.apple.com%252Fc%252F6438ebc13eb4937a89f42b80f9064d41%252Fitc%252Fjs%252Fcompiled%252Flib%252Fvendor.js%253A25%253A7800%250A%2520%2520%2520%2520at%2520https%253A%252F%252Fitunesconnect.apple.com%252Fc%252F6438ebc13eb4937a89f42b80f9064d41%252Fitc%252Fjs%252Fcompiled%252Flib%252Fvendor.js%253A25%253A13693%250A%2520%2520%2520%2520at%2520Array.forEach%2520(native)%250A%2520%2520%2520%2520at%2520f%2520(https%253A%252F%252Fitunesconnect.apple.com%252Fc%252F6438ebc13eb4937a89f42b80f9064d41%252Fitc%252Fjs%252Fcompiled%252Flib%252Fvendor.js%253A25%253A775)%250A%2520%2520%2520%2520at%2520e%2520(https%253A%252F%252Fitunesconnect.apple.com%252Fc%252F6438ebc13eb4937a89f42b80f9064d41%252Fitc%252Fjs%252Fcompiled%252Flib%252Fvendor.js%253A25%253A13555)%250A%2520%2520%2520%2520at%2520https%253A%252F%252Fitunesconnect.apple.com%252Fc%252F6438ebc13eb4937a89f42b80f9064d41%252Fitc%252Fjs%252Fcompiled%252Flib%252Fvendor.js%253A25%253A13632%250A%2520%2520%2520%2520at%2520Array.forEach%2520(native)%0A%20%20%20%20at%20Error%20(native)%0A%20%20%20%20at%20https:%2F%2Fitunesconnect.apple.com%2Fc%2F6438ebc13eb4937a89f42b80f9064d41%2Fitc%2Fjs%2Fcompiled%2Flib%2Fvendor.js:25:449%0A%20%20%20%20at%20https:%2F%2Fitunesconnect.apple.com%2Fc%2F6438ebc13eb4937a89f42b80f9064d41%2Fitc%2Fjs%2Fcompiled%2Flib%2Fvendor.js:25:13943%0A%20%20%20%20at%20Array.forEach%20(native)%0A%20%20%20%20at%20f%20(https:%2F%2Fitunesconnect.apple.com%2Fc%2F6438ebc13eb4937a89f42b80f9064d41%2Fitc%2Fjs%2Fcompiled%2Flib%2Fvendor.js:25:775)%0A%20%20%20%20at%20e%20(https:%2F%2Fitunesconnect.apple.com%2Fc%2F6438ebc13eb4937a89f42b80f9064d41%2Fitc%2Fjs%2Fcompiled%2Flib%2Fvendor.js:25:13555)%0A%20%20%20%20at%20https:%2F%2Fitunesconnect.apple.com%2Fc%2F6438ebc13eb4937a89f42b80f9064d41%2Fitc%2Fjs%2Fcompiled%2Flib%2Fvendor.js:25:13632%0A%20%20%20%20at%20Array.forEach%20(native)%0A%20%20%20%20at%20f%20(https:%2F%2Fitunesconnect.apple.com%2Fc%2F6438ebc13eb4937a89f42b80f9064d41%2Fitc%2Fjs%2Fcompiled%2Flib%2Fvendor.js:25:775)%0A%20%20%20%20at%20e%20(https:%2F%2Fitunesconnect.apple.com%2Fc%2F6438ebc13eb4937a89f42b80f9064d41%2Fitc%2Fjs%2Fcompiled%2Flib%2Fvendor.js:25:13555)

I tried accessing from different browsers and computers.. They're still the same. Is it something related specifically to my account?

**Anyone currently experiencing this?** Also, do you happen to know the direct link to the app pre-release page? (in case the error is just on the menu page so maybe I can bypass it with a direct link).

For AngularJS pros, is there somehow a way to monkey-patch this from the client side, to make this error go away? Unfortunately, I didn't have the POST URL for submitting reviews in my browser history, it was done in a different machine a few weeks ago.

Comment: Same here! I'm hanging at Apple Developer support line…

Comment: Their support email is reading: `Thank you for contacting XX_Group_XX about the iTunes Connect error you received.` I wonder that's `XX_Group_XX`…

Comment: Same here just wanted to do the ITC side of the app update. This is not the first time this happens to me. I already had a lot of bad luck today with Xcode forgetting about my Dev Profile. This certainly doesn't make me fonder of developing for the iOS platform.

Comment: 12 minutes waiting but nothing concrete, just that Apple will send me another email with request from more information…

Comment: I still get a white page after logging in due to an angular error. I know these errors since I'm using angular myself. It mostly happens due to very obvious syntax errors/undefined variables in imported modules. However, angular catches anything that goes wrong during bootstrapping and then throws these errors when resolving dependencies.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's been down for about 12 hours.

I heard some people wiped their browser cache and that cleared the error (I tried it but it didn't work), I doubt there's a client side fix for this, as it's most likely going to be the javascript that apple use.

The best thing to do is probably just wait it out really, maybe do some more polishing on your app if it needs it or some PR etc.

Comment: Just tried this with chrome, no dice.

Comment: I tried it with FF, Chrome and in Safari this morning, but no change.

Comment: I'm trying to edit an app's listing and can't upload screenshots because the device/screen size buttons under 'App Video Preview and Screenshots' aren't appearing.
I see an angular error in the console and suspect that.
They did appear earlier, then my session timed out and now I can't get them to appear despite trying several browsers, clearing cache, cookies etc.

Comment: I just submitted my app in iTunesConnect using Safari just a while ago. Go check it out guys!

Comment: Yup, back yesterday. Thanks.

Comment: clearing all the cookies for itunesconnect.apple.com fixed the issue for me just now (chrome)

Answer (score 0):

Direct link to the Sales and Trends. https://reportingitc2.apple.com/

I'm seeing an angular exception on the site again.

Direct link to pre release page isn't working either. https://itunesconnect.apple.com/WebObjects/iTunesConnect.woa/ra/ng/app/-your-app-id-goes-here-/pre/builds